# Handle key press by function in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-strap

in my component I am using VueStrap's modal like this:

```html
<template>
    <modal-window v-model="show" v-on:keyup="keyHandler($event)" @ok="submit()" @cancel="cancel()" @closed="close()" ... >
       ...
    </modal-window>
 ...
</template>
<script> 
    ...
    methods: {
       keyHandler (event) {
           console.log(event);
       }
    },...
</script>
```

I want handle key press when that modal is opened and ensure submit modal when enter pressed or close modal when esc pressed.

I added custom function `keyHandler` which is unfortunately never fired. Can you tell me how to fix code to handle key press in that function? Or when is better way how to close and submit vue strap modal I will be grateful for advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can attach your event handler to `window`, that way you can receive all key events and act accordingly depending on your modal's state:

```js
Vue.component('modal', {
  template: '<div>test modal</div>',
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  created() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      if (e.key == 'Escape') {
        this.showModal = !this.showModal;
      }
    });
  },
  data: {
    showModal: true
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <modal v-show="showModal"></modal>
</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry but I find out right now that enter and esc are not handled, just when I am in input ... other keys works every time, do you have idea what should be problem?

Comment: maybe you're catching the event on your input and stopping propagation..

Comment: or maybe you're using `keypress`, try using `keydown` instead

Comment: this worked but I had to add the event listener on 'mounted' not 'created'. The window object did not exist yet on 'created' in my project

Comment: Alternatively wrap the window.addEvent.... in $nextThick

Answer (score 9):

easiest way

```
<input v-on:keyup.13="whatkey()" type="text"> <br>
```

looks for if the enter key is pressed then fires a method called whatkey.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you may want to consider using the `v-hotkey` directive for key input in Vue ([docs](https://dafrok.github.io/v-hotkey/#/), [github](https://github.com/Dafrok/v-hotkey)).  This will keep your code relatively clean and simple if you must consider several different key inputs.

1.  Install it:

```
npm i --save v-hotkey
```

2. Have Vue 'use' it:

   import VueHotkey from "v-hotkey";
   Vue.use(VueHotkey);

3.  Apply it to your Vue components, like so:

```html
<template>
    <modal-window ... v-hotkey="keymap">
       ...
    </modal-window>
</template>
<script>
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      showModal: false
    };
  },
  computed: {
    keymap() {
      return {
        "esc": this.toggleModal
      };
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleModal() {
      this.showModal = !this.showModal;
    }
  }
</script>
```