# How to use "v-on:keyup.enter" on nativescript-vue? (not returnPress)

Tags: vue.js, nativescript-vue, vue-directives

1. I was making an app with NativeScript-Vue but v-on:keyup.enter="entered" doesn't work at Android. code is below.

File Structure:

```
TodoInput.vue:
...
<TextField v-model="newTodoItem" hint="Type what you have to do" width="70%" horizontalAlignment="left" v-on:keyup.enter="entered" />
...
methods: {
    entered() {
        console.log("entered");
    }
}
...
```

2. Expected result:

If the "Done" key is pressed on keyboard, console.log("entered"); must execute.

Comment: Have you gone through this ??? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50395674/handle-key-press-by-function-in-vuejs

Comment: not just vue.js. it's nativescript-vue