# How do you add a Global event in a website?

Tags: javascript, function, vuejs2, show, event-listener

The function I am trying to build is. I want to show a login page only when I press two keyboard keys. I tried adding an event listener to a hidden button, but it doesn't seem to be working. Also I am trying to do this in Vue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50395674/handle-key-press-by-function-in-vuejs

Comment: Duplicate: [Handle key press by function in VueJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50395674/handle-key-press-by-function-in-vuejs)